# Match a string consisting of precisely two given sub-strings with a possibility of only whitespace characters in between

Tags: c#, regex

**Input**: `This AbT5xYAppleUvW is a test.....`

Input will be file content coming from sources I don't have a control on. I need to replace `AbT5xYApple` with `FruitApple` whether there is a whitespace characters (newline, carriage return, space etc.) in between `AbT5xY` and `Apple` or not. E.g. `AbT5xY Apple` or `AbT5xY\nApple` also need to be replaced with `FruitApple`

**Note** I'm using C# regular expressions

Following does not work:

```
string input = Regex.Replace(input, "AbT5xY\S+AppleUvW", "FruitApple");
```

Comment: try this then `AbT5xY\s*AppleUvW` note: `\s*` not `\S+`

Comment: @alphabravo Your suggestion worked (thank you). Also, I need to have my pattern as `AbT5xY\s*Apple` only - no need for `UvW` at the end. For benefit of other readers you may want to change your comment to a response - and I'll mark that as an `answer`.

Comment: Note that in case there are any other non-word chars (not just whitespace) in between the words, you may replace `\s*` with `\W*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per comments above, use this pattern `AbT5xY\s*Apple`

```
AbT5xY          # "AbT5xY"
\s              # <whitespace character>
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
Apple           # "Apple"
```